# Is AWS Enforce MFA policy AllowIndividualUserToDeactivateOnlyTheirOwnMFAOnlyWhenUsingMFA mandatory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

I'm setting up MFA for one test account and learning few things while doing so. Went through [AWS Documentation for the default Policy JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_mfa-selfmanage.html) which is quite self explanatory except for the SID: ***AllowIndividualUserToDeactivateOnlyTheirOwnMFAOnlyWhenUsingMFA***

1) I'm trying to figure out what are the possible scenarios this policy is needed?

2) Is it mandatory or a best practice to keep this in the enforce MFA policy? I want to enforce MFA once and ensure the users cannot deactivate (only admin should) it. Is there any drawback to my idea?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy you mention allow users to deactivate their own MFA device. And they can only do it if they athenticate with MFA.

```
    {
        "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToDeactivateOnlyTheirOwnMFAOnlyWhenUsingMFA",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:DeactivateMFADevice"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}",
            "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want each user to decide if they will use MFA or not, yes this policy is a best practice. It is not mandatory.

But as you want to enforce it, you should not allow the normal users to have the permission `iam:DeactivateMFADevice`. Only admins should have it.

To enforce MFA, the important part is the condition:

```
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
            }
        }
```